# firebase+vue.js данные из базы данных не приходят в темплейт

Tags: vue.js, firebase

**console.firebase.google.com:**

структура данных БД - http://joxi.ru/DmBg8lOTwjK7M2

правило:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

**Main.js:**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueFire from 'vuefire'
import App from './App.vue'
Vue.use(VueFire)
```

**App.vue:**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="place in places">
       <div>{{place.to}}</div>
    </div>
    {{places}}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import Firebase from 'firebase';

  /* конфигурация с console.firebase.google.com   */

  let config = {
    apiKey: "...",
    authDomain: "...",
    databaseURL: "...",
    projectId: "...",
    storageBucket: "...",
    messagingSenderId: "..."
  };


  let app = Firebase.initializeApp(config);
  let db = app.database();

  console.log(db);
  /* выводит Database {repo_: Repo, root_: Reference, INTERNAL: 
  DatabaseInternals}  */


  export default {
    firebase: {
      places: db.ref('places')
    },
  }
</script>
```

никаких ошибок консоль не показывает, в {{places}} - пусто. 
vue dev tools показывает - http://joxi.ru/krDgzLXTE3VNRA

подскажите плиз что не так

Answer (score 1):

Нашел ошибку. Данные забивал в Cloud Firestore, а не в Realtime Database. Переделал все заработало.